# how to show an array using Ajax and Symfony

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, symfony

i am trying to show a consult which have an array with arrays in symfony using Ajax and json, this is my ajax's script :

```
    <script>
    var boton=document.getElementById("form_Boton");
    function ajax() {
        var nombre=$('#form_nombre').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{{ path('buscar_porCriterio') }}",
            data: ({nombre: nombre}),
            dataType:"json",
            beforeSend:function () {
                alert("enviará a: "+nombre);
            },

            success:function (resp) {
                if(resp!=""){
                    $('#resultados').html(resp["nombre"]+" "+resp["apellido"]+" "+resp["residencia"]);
                }
                if(resp==""){
                    alert("NO SE ENCONTRO NADA");
                }


            }
        })
    }
    boton.addEventListener("click",ajax);

</script>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function PorCriterioAction(Request $request){
    if(!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        throw new Exception("Error, NO ES AJAX");
    }
    $nombre=$request->request->get('nombre');
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $encontradas=$em->getRepository('FormulariosBundle:persona')->findBynombre($nombre);
    if ($encontradas == null) {
        $response = new Response("VACIO  " . $nombre . " Sorry");
        return $response;
    }
    else{
        $persona_encontrada = (array("id" => $encontradas->getId(),
            "nombre" => $encontradas->getNombre(),
            "apellido" => $encontradas->getApellido(),
            "residencia" => $encontradas->getResidencia()
        ));
        $response= new JsonResponse($persona_encontrada);
        return $response;}}
```

what i need is get all data from my DB whose name be $nombre, and show every data in my div 'resultados'. but. when i realize my search, symfony show me this exception: 
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV9s7.png)

my question is: How can i do to pass every data of that consult to my div 'resultados'?

as you see, i want to show such consult in a div whose id is "resultados" but does not work, can you help me please? i am a beginner in symfony and i have to make this University Proyect and finish my study, thanks for your answer

**EDIT # 2**

this is the change to my controller:

```
public function PorCriterioAction(Request $request){
    if(!$request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        throw new Exception("Error, NO ES AJAX");
    }
    $nombre=$request->request->get('nombre');
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $encontradas=$em->getRepository('FormulariosBundle:persona')->findBynombre($nombre);
    if ($encontradas == null) {
        $response = new Response("VACIO  " . $nombre . " Sorry");
        return $response;
    }
    else{
        foreach ($encontradas as $Item){
            $persona_encontrada = (array("id" => $Item->getId(),
                "nombre" => $Item->getNombre(),
                "apellido" => $Item->getApellido(),
                "residencia" => $Item->getResidencia()
            ));
            array_push($persona_encontrada,$Item);
        }
            $response= new JsonResponse($persona_encontrada);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

is this what you need? [responseText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV9s7.png)

Comment: You shouldn't post images of your code but instead your actual code. You won't get much help if you post just images. Can you click `edit` on your post and add the actual code. Learn how to format it properly.

Comment: I edited my answer, please try it!

Comment: See my EDIT #2 section. If you can upvote my comments if you think i helped, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I need to see the `text` JSON response NOT an image of what your web page looks like!

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I see from the response, there is only 1 id in the response. So it's working as expected!

Comment: ok i understand, but what is the way to show all elements of my array in the div 'resultados' ?

Comment: I'm not sure since I'm not very familiar with jQuery. It appears to be something in your `success` response function. But I'm not sure what that is doing.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe $encontradas is a results set so try this:

```
foreach( $encontradas as $item){
    $persona_encontrada = (array(
        "id" => $item->getId(),
        "nombre" => $item->getNombre(),
        "apellido" => $item->getApellido(),
        "residencia" => $item->getResidencia()
    ));
}
```

Let us know the result.

---

EDIT #2

I see the problem. Since it iterates through the array, you want `$persona_encontrada` to be an array and then use the PHP `array_push` to add array elements to it. You could do it like so:

```
$persona_encontrada = array();

foreach( $encontradas as $item){
    $element = array(
        "id" => $item->getId(),
        "nombre" => $item->getNombre(),
        "apellido" => $item->getApellido(),
        "residencia" => $item->getResidencia()
    );

    array_push( $persona_encontrada, $element);
}
```

By the way, although this will work for you, it might not be the best way to do something like this. But it will work.

Comment: Hello alvin, i update my question, i hope you can understand what i need. thanks!

Comment: Amazing! it is work! thank you very much! so, how can i do to pass every element of my array to the view?  because just arrive the last element of the array (because the for it travels for the complete array)

Comment: excuse me, but i need the way to show every array item in my div 'resultados', when i do my search, only shows the last element of the array.  is there any way to show EVERY element of the array in my div 'resultados'? is there any way to edit the method "success" and my variable 'rest' gets every element of my 'response'? 
you really have helped me, but i really need this last info, please, and thanks

Comment: I need to know what is exactly returned by `resp`. Can you edit your post and show that. I suspect with the EDIT #2 change, there is arrays within arrays; so I need to see the JSON response that gets returned.

Comment: how can i show you the text json response? i don't know what are you talking about :/

Comment: Press a button that makes an AJAX call, and then use your browser developer tools to get the response. For example in FireFox, take a look at the `Network` tab.